# tidb-lightning.toml got permission denied in WSL

Tags: permission-denied, toml, tidb

I tried to upload my SQL files to TiDB Cluster via tidb-lightning.toml,
and here is the result of my nohup.out:

```
tiup is checking updates for component tidb-lightning ...
Starting component `tidb-lightning`: /tidb-lightning/v7.0.0/tidb-lightning -config tidb-lightning.toml
Verbose debug logs will be written to tidb-lightning.log

tidb lightning encountered error: [Lightning:Storage:ErrStorageUnknown]list file failed: open /mnt/c/System Volume Information: permission denied
```

Answer (score 0):

Look like tidb lightning try to use `/mnt/c/System` as its storage but permission denied, so you can resolve the permission about `/mnt/c/System`, or
change tidb-lightning.toml to use another path as tidb lighning storage.